# Why value variable is not changed in function?

Tags: bash

Why `var` does not change in the first case and changes in the second?

```
#!/bin/bash
var=0

changeVar()
{
  var=1
}
```

First case:

```
tmp=$(changeVar)
echo "var = $var"         // var = 0
```

Second case:

```
changeVar
echo "var = $var"         // var = 1
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Execution-Environment) would tell you:

> Command substitution, commands grouped with parentheses, and
>   asynchronous commands are invoked in a subshell environment that is a
>   duplicate of the shell environment.

In the first case, the `$(...)` (i.e. command substitution) causes the function to be invoked in a *subshell*.  As such, the change in the value of the variable is not visible.